# Ways to parse docs and normalize rows

Tags: python, string, normalization

I feel as if I oversimplify/overcomplexify doc parsing at times, here is what I often do:

```
data = open('data.txt', 'rb').read()

for line in data.split('\n'):
    if not line.strip():
        continue
```

and this:

```
import csv

filenames=['first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'postcode', 'telephone_no', ]
reader = csv.DictReader(open('data.csv', 'rb'), filenames=filenames)

for line in reader:
    if line['email'].strip()
        email = line['email'].strip()
    if line['first_name'].strip()
        first_name= line['first_name'].strip().capitalize()
    if line['last_name'].strip()
        last_name = line['last_name'].strip().capitalize()
    if line['postcode'].strip()
        postcode= line['postcode'].strip().upper().replace(' ','')
    if line['telephone_no'].strip()
        telephone_no = line['telephone_no'].strip()
```

and this:

```
item = " 4 -2,5456+263 @5"
item = ''.join([char for char in item if char.isdigit()])

item = "+34 0394-234553"
item = item.replace('+','').replace(' ','').replace('-','')
```

---

**Any tips/suggestions on improvements/alternatives?** :)

Comment: Open you file like this: `data = open("data.txt", "rb")`, and then this `file line in data:` will iterate over the lines. No `split()` required. Also, consider using `with` to make sure the file is closed.

Comment: @Space_C0wb0y: you meant probably `for line in data:`

Comment: @eumiro: Indeed I did. Cannot edit anymore though, comment too old.

Answer (score 2):

You could make the the list of non-empty lines a one-liner

```
lines = filter(None, (line.strip() for line in open('data.txt', 'rb').readlines()))
```

**Fastest way to remove everything except certain characters**

Use `__contains__` method of a string constant with `filter` (`filter` returns string if used with string). So you could remove non-digit characters this way:

```
import string
filter(string.digits.__contains__, " 4 -2,5456+263 @5")
```

Comment: @lmran: awesome! I really like the __contains__ example a lot, thanks for sharing :)

Answer (score 1):

```
with open('data.txt', 'rb') as myfile:
    for line in myfile:
        if not line:
            continue
```

As you probably want to do something with the line, it can be simplified further:

```
with open('data.txt', 'rb') as myfile:
    for line in myfile:
        if line:
           do_whateveryouwant(line)
```